# Roll up using Flow builder Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-flow

I have two custom object expense and cost centre ,cost centre is lookup from expense object,so using flow builder i want to update All Forecast Spending and My Forecast Spending with related expenses.how to acheive this use case?

i want to update cost centre fields all forecast spending and my forecast spending whenever is expenses is created ,updated ,deleted